# How can I express "a particular/a certain" thing?

Tags: words, usage

I am studying vocabulary and I came across the word [然る](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%84%B6%E3%82%8B), either read as さる or しかる (usually written in Kana) and means "A Particular/A Certain" noun. However, there was only one example sentence on there and it wasn't marked as a Common Word, which seems to be a red flag for me in terms of learning the correct vocabulary.

How can I use さる／しかる to express "a particular/a certain" thing? Secondly, is there a better or more natural way to express this phrase?

Example idea:

> 卒業するように、さる授業を取らなければいけません。
>   In order to graduate, you must take a certain class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always read as さる when it means "a certain ～". You can think of it basically as a literary version of [ある meaning "a certain ～" or "one ～"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/50257/5010). In relatively casual situations, さる sounds more or less "serious", and it sometimes has a nuance of "don't pry into this".

- ある授業を取らないといけません → sounds natural and neutral
- さる授業を取らないといけません → uncommon; may sound like this class is somehow special/problematic when used in a casual blog article or such
- ある会社 → neutral
- さる会社 → maybe the speaker does not want to disclose the name of the company

Comment: Ah, I always forget about ある. Thanks for the response.